# Upload to AWS S3 with AWS PHP SDK fails authentication

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using version 3.67.5 of AWS SDK PHP to upload files to S3. The code is in an Heroku dyno.

I've created the access keys, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and set them as configuration variables in the Heroku instance. I know that they are there, because with getenv() I 've outputted them.

I'm using the following code:

```
try {
   //Create a S3Client
   $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region' => 'some-region',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]);
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket'     => 'some-bucket',
        'Key'        => $fileName,
        'SourceFile' => $this->getParameter('photos_directory') . $fileName,
    ]);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Still, uploading a file, it shows the following error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: "Cannot read credentials from /app/.aws/credentials"
```

I've tested passing a new element 'credentials' in the constructor, like they do in theirs [unit tests](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.67.5/tests/S3/S3ClientTest.php), and the error is the same.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in reading the credentials from your credentials file, not that the credentials are wrong. Are you sure your credentials file is in it's corrected place, is readable to PHP, etc.? Use PHP to read the file contents and write it out and see if it can even do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in defining the profile as "default". When I removed the profile parameter, the error disappeared.

When using the latest version, 3.67.8, the following error occurred:

```
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https: // some-url` resulted in a` 403 Forbidden`
```

Anyway, in my case, and in both versions, omitting the profile parameter was the solution.

Comment: Thanks @foxtrot.  You saved me hours.  You would think this would be in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make sure that the file `/app/.aws/credentials` does not exist. If it does exist and is empty, your will have a credentials error.

Step 2: Change your client code to the following:

```
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;

$s3Client = new S3Client([
     'profile' => 'default',
     'region' => 'some-region',
     'version' => 'latest',
     credentials' => CredentialProvider::env()
]);
```

If this does not solve your problem, then either you have mispelled the environment variables or they are not exported so that your program can see them.

If this does work, then there are invalid credentials somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, doesn't work. Don't know where is the problem. Also couldn't find in Heroku how to check if there isn't any file in that path.

Comment: bit late to the party but for others who want to check for a file in the app path use: `heroku run 'ls -la /app'`